# What is the correct way to scope user data in a rails shopify app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

For locally stored data, what is the best way to scope entities to the currently logged in shop owner?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you talking about data you've created and want to upload, or data you've pulled from a shop and want to store locally?

Comment: Data I create and want to store locally. I think the answer is: ShopifyAPI::Shop.current.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best idea is to store the .myshopify domain. This is a unique identifier that never changes for the shop and you need it to make requests to the shop. The shop id is unique as well, but essentially useless for anything you might want to do.

Answer (score 1):

After a little poking, I realized `ShopifyAPI::Shop.current.id` is the correct way.